# Set secret key of "encrypt node" from flow or global variable in node red

Tags: node-red

How can we set the flow/global variable value to secret key in "Encrypt Node".

[image]

https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-crypto-js-plus

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66133035/edit) the question to include a link to the node on https://flows.nodered.org

Answer (score 1):

Having looked at the source code for the node, the short answer is that you don't. It doesn't support taking key or algorithm values from anywhere but the config dialoge.

Also as a rule, nodes should not use flow/context variables as config input.

What you can do is have the values in the configuration replaced by environment variables read at startup. Details of how to use environment variables can be found [here](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/environment-variables).